# How to do 2 way communication between server and client using sockets in JAVA?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, io, java-stream

I have made 2 classes, one is `client.java` and one is `server.java`. I am using `socket` to communicate between them. The server and client connects but don't send data and stays connected.

`client.java`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 42069);
  System.out.println("Connected to the server!");
        
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
      (new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        
  out.write("hi from client");
  System.out.println(in.readLine());
        
  s.close();
}
```

`server.java`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {               
  ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(42069);
  System.out.println("\nWaiting For Connection...");
  Socket s = ss.accept();
  System.out.println("\nConnected to the client!");
            
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
      (newOutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            
  System.out.println(in.readLine());
  out.write("hi from server");
            
}
```

when both connect, they stay like this:
`s.jaerverva`

```
Waiting For Connection...

Connected to the client!
```

`client.java`

```
Connected to the server!
```

when i terminate the client, i get this error on the server:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:177)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:162)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
    at HTTP.server.main(server.java:14)
```

Comment: what do you mean by URLConnection.openStream(), i didn't understant it.

Comment: Sorry the correct method is URLConnection.getOutputStream()

Comment: BTW, I highly recommend you use Websockets over plain the old Sockets. Websockets handle so much plumbing for you.

Comment: can you explain `URLConnection.getOutputStream()`?